# Struts2 error handling - exception stack not found

Tags: error-handling, exception, struts2, scope, stack-trace

I've encountered a strange thing. I have configured exception handling in struts 2.1.8 like stated [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/exception-configuration.html), only that I redirect to an action instead to JSP (to send emails...).

So, in the action I have

```
ActionContext ac = ActionContext.getContext();
String stackTrace = null;
if(ac.getValueStack().findValue("exceptionStack") != null) {            
    stackTrace =  ac.getValueStack().findValue("exceptionStack").toString();
} else {
    stackTrace = "Stack trace not found!";
}
```

I had to make this if-else because sometimes the value is null. I haven't found the difference why sometimes I get the stack trace and sometimes I don't. All the errors happen in Struts2.

Did anyone had similar problem? Can anybody directs me where is the problem?

Comment: your question has saved my time! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you map exception with chain result type you'll keep the same request and so the same ValueStack.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution - just to change result type. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, `ValueStack` is per-request (each thread has its own), so redirecting to a new action will cause you to lose any data you had in the previous request's `ValueStack`.

With that said, what is your goal here? The link you provided explains how to map different types of exceptions to custom error pages (or results). Why doesn't that work for you? You mention you want to send emails -- are you sending an email notification about the actual exception (and stack trace)?

If you can expand a bit about what you are trying to do, then perhaps we can give you some guidance.

Comment: Aha. ValueStack is per-request - this is important. Now I have to find out how to get ValueStack with the exception.